# PHP: PATCH method fails when others succeed

Tags: php, api, restful-url

I have a an API I'm using a variety of methods on. GET works fine as do the others I am testing. When using `PATCH`, it gives errors despite the documentation showing it's enabled.

The errors are:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in upload.php on line 20

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api-domain/answers/331): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in oracle_upload.php on line 20
Error
```

Line 20 is

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://api-domain/answers/331', FALSE, $content)
```

As for the $content variable:

```
$postData = array(        
    'solution' => 'Testing 123'
);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'content' => json_encode($postData)
    ),
    "ssl"=>array(
        "allow_self_signed"=>true,
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false
    )
));
```

Please note, https://api-domain is a fake addy
Thanks

Comment: Where is the $content? can you show it?

Comment: Amended to show this

Comment: I posted a answer that helped me onces, if it does not, I suggest using CURL, its a bit messy but gets the work done.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file change this line or add.

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

`allow_url_fopen = On`